# X toolkit, How to access rendered canvas data in Chromium

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chromium, xtk

With the http://lessons.goxtk.com/00/ and I am trying to get the data as an image ( toDataURL('image/webp') ) from the canvas in Chromium  31.0.1650.63 (debian). After loading the page, I typed at the javascript console the followings :

```
canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; // get canvas
canvas.toDataURL('image/webp'); // get data in a Chromium-compatible format
```

But, what I got as data is a black picture at the size of the canvas, without the xtk rendered content. Is there a way to access the xtk's canvas data ?

Thanks in advance